# update UITableView rows and sections using NSFetchedRequestController and without reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I wasn't able to find an answer for this specific problem so here it is.

I have multiple VC's under a UITabBarController, each has a UITableView and use an NSFetchedRequestController to get data.  In each VC I have a refreshFetchedRequest method, which I call on viewDidAppear to start reflecting any change from one VC to another.  It basically just does a performFetch.

This problem could be easily worked around by calling reloadData after refreshFetchedRequest, but I want row/section insertion/deletion animations.

So to summarize on viewDidAppear, I do:

```
[self refreshFetchedRequest];
[tableView beginUpdates];
// compare cached rows/sections with NSFetchedRequestController - how?
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Where do I get the existing cached UITableView rows and sections to compare them with the refreshed NSFetchedResultsController?

UPDATE:

I am now doing this in my viewDidAppear method:

```
NSFetchedRequestController *frcBeforeUpdate = frc;
[self refreshFetchedRequest]; // refreshes my frc property
[tableView beginUpdates];
// compare frcBeforeUpdate with frc here
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is then solved by making sure that either:

- the two viewControllers use the same managedObjectContext
- you listen for managedObjectContextDidSave notification and call mergeChangesFromManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification on the managedObject you use for the fetchedResultsController.

In both cases you will get the delegate callbacks you are looking for.

Comment: the 2 VCs use the same moc and knowing when to look for changes isn't a problem, because I am doing it asynchronously.

Comment: If you are using the MOC to update your UI, you need a MOC with concurrencyTypeMainQueue. If both viewController already use the same MOC, you only need to implement the NFRC-delegate methods. Or I don't understand your structure and wishes well enough to provide a better answer.

Comment: actually I'm not expecting any delegate callbacks here

Comment: Why not? You have an NSFetchedRC, so if you set the view controller as the delegate, you WILL get delegate callbacks when changes to the managedObjectContext happen. The MOC in which the managedObjects change has to be the MOC that you used to set the NSFRC up with off course.

Comment: I guess I wasn't explicit in the OP.  But I want to perform a single batch table insert/deletion update on viewDidAppear and I have an FRC structure.  Implementing the FRC delegate methods would at best give me the callbacks as changes are made from other VCs of the UITabBarController.

Comment: Yes, that is why the delegate will give you: willChangeContent (indicating the start of multiple changes) where you can call [tableView beginUpdates] and didChangeContent (indicating the end of multiple changes) where you can call [tableView endUpdates]. Somewhere in between you have to then actually reload sections or rows, or insert or remove rows and or sections.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after re-reading you question, I think I now understand what you want: you want the tableview to update with animations, AFTER it has appeared again. So you want to delay the updates to the tableView.

Use NSFetchedResultsController. Instead of calling the relevant update-method on your tableView in respons to those methods, store the changes in an NSDictionary, or a custom class, where you store the index paths for the type of changes. Then in viewDidAppear, you are going to call something like:

```
[tableView beginUpdates]
for (NSIndexPath * anIndexPath in self.cachedChanges[updates]){
    [tableView reloadRowAtIndepath: anINdexPath];
}
for (NSIndexPath * indexPath in self.cachedChanges[deletions]){
    [tableView deleteRowAtindexPath: indexPath]
}
// ... more like this for sections and insertions
[tableView endUpdates];
self.cachedChanges = nil;
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I copied what I want to show you :P I guess the back-and-forth has helped me understand it better

Comment: So does this answer help you on your way, or is there still something unclear?

Comment: you want me give you reps and mark this the correct answer?

Comment: No that is Ok, i was just wandering if I now understood your question and my suggestion was actually answering it :) .

Comment: I think you're closer than when you suggested to use NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate though where I was initially stuck was thinking there could be a be cache (like you're suggesting in the code above) I could use to compare my NSFetchedResultsController after I call performFetch to include all the batch updates I need.  All I needed to do was to save the NSFetchedResultsController state before the performFetch call and then compare sections and rows after and call table inserts and deletions.  I up voted all your answers because they helped me analyze the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Cool. There are some questions on how to use UICollectionView with NSFetchedResultsController here on SO too. UICollectionView does't (didn't?) work well with NSFRC, so people came up with a caching mechanism similar (but more detailed) to what I try to describe here. I think if you search for it you will find some very useful bits. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the viewController as a delegate of the fetchedResultsController. Check the documentation on NSFetchedResultsController, it shows you copy-and-pastable code to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I guess I still have the problem that the changes are happening on a different VC.  That's why I'm calling the UITableView updates block in the viewDidAppear method.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this wouldn't work.  NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate is for when you don't need to call performFetch in order to synchronize the UITableViewDataSource.  Since the changes are made on another VC, the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods are not being called.  Essentially my problem is one that requires knowing how to compose a batch update, whereas using NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate is for individual updates in a somewhat synchronous fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You should to become a delegate NSFetchedResultsController and process delegate's methods following way:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    UITableViewRowAnimation animationType = UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic;
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:animationType];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:animationType];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableViewRowAnimation animationType = UITableViewRowAnimationFade;
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:animationType];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:animationType];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:animationType];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:animationType];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Also you can see a good example of adding new records to a table across NSFetchedResultsController by creating an empty Master-Detail Application project on the Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)animateRefreshFetchedResultsControllers
{
    NSFetchedResultsController *frc3 = _frc1;
    [self refreshFetchedResultsControllers];

    NSMutableArray *oldSectionNames = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSMutableArray *newSectionNames = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> section in frc3.sections) {
        [oldSectionNames addObject:section.name];
    }
    for (id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> section in _frc1.sections) {
        [newSectionNames addObject:section.name];
    }

    [_tableView beginUpdates];
    NSMutableIndexSet *sectionsToDelete = [NSMutableIndexSet new];
    for (NSString *sectionName in oldSectionNames) {
        if (![newSectionNames containsObject:sectionName]) {
            [sectionsToDelete addIndex:[oldSectionNames indexOfObject:sectionName]];
        }
    }
    [_tableView deleteSections:sectionsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

    NSMutableIndexSet *sectionsToInsert = [NSMutableIndexSet new];
    for (NSString *sectionName in newSectionNames) {
        if (![oldSectionNames containsObject:sectionName]) {
            [sectionsToInsert addIndex:[newSectionNames indexOfObject:sectionName]];
        }
    }
    [_tableView insertSections:sectionsToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

    NSMutableArray *rowsToInsert = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i = 0; i < sectionsToInsert.count; i++) {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> section = _frc1.sections[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < section.numberOfObjects; j++) {
            NSIndexPath *rowIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i];
            [rowsToInsert addObject:rowIndexPath];
        }
    }
    [_tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

    [_tableView endUpdates];
}
```